# Do Swift and Objective-C share the same native API?

Tags: ios, swift

I can't get my hands on Apple's eBook as my Apple account is registered in another country, but I was wondering if anybody knows if Objective-C and Swift share the same native API? Or is Swift a completely 'new'?

Comment: [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/), [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/)

Answer (score 3):

Swift has its own API for basic classes like Array and Dictionary, but it also has access to the entire Objective-C codebase like UIKit, Cocoa and Foundation.

Answer (score 3):

Kind of a rambling answer but a grab bag of things I've so far learnt from the book:

Swift is statically typed. It does not use `objc_msgSend` underneath. Apple provides bridging between the two to make classes of either language callable from the other but, underneath it, the way functions are called is very different.

The APIs exposed describe the same system — an application with screens and windows, views and view controllers, storyboards and segues, StoreKit, CoreLocation, etc — but in resultantly different ways. To what extent you'd say they're the same API is moot.

Generics are now a language feature. With that and strict typing, collections are now typed and look a lot like STL generics; e.g. you declare a dictionary with keys of type `Int` and values of type `String` and trying to put any other kind of key/value pair in raises a runtime exception.

Swift elevates the difference between mutable things and immutable things to the language level for the new category of value types via a distinction between variables and constants. This automatically extends the distinction to Foundation collections. So with those there is no more need manually to manage `copy` versus `mutableCopy` (versus `retain`, whether ARC implied or explicit).

Because the language is not dynamic, Cocoa mainstays like key-value observing are not available.

Swift follows the C# lead on structs versus classes — structs can have methods but live on the stack. With blocks being a notable special case, Objective-C objects could not live on the stack. This has some effect on the pragmatic thinking about how data flows.

Swift has a language-level concept of a tuple, which is like a mix between an array and a class. It allows ordered or named fields to be combined into a single unit but is intended for restricted, in-place use e.g. to indicate return results where it's not worth the weight of defining yet another class. That naturally affects the API.

Variables of all types — including those that will usually compile down as though C primitives — can now be optional. `nil` may be assigned to any optional variable to mean that it does not currently have a value. It may not be assigned to any variable that is not optional. So `NSNotFound`, etc, are gone.

Comment: "Swift elevates the difference between mutable things and immutable things to the language level via a distinction between variables and constants." For value types maybe. But mutable/immutable for value types is pretty much meaningless anyway; any change to a value type is semantically equivalent to just assigning a new value. For reference types (reference to class instances), whether the variable is assignable is unrelated to whether the object pointed to is mutable.

Comment: @newacct on the other hand: "If you create an array or a dictionary and assign it to a variable, the collection that is created will be mutable. ... Conversely, if you assign an array or a dictionary to a constant, that array or dictionary is immutable, and its size cannot be changed."; the mutable/immutable difference between those types was handled at a framework (/API) level and is now handled at the language level. So I stand by my statement as applied to whether Swift "share[s] the same native API" as asked.

Comment: That's only because `Array` and `Dictionary` are structs, which are value types. It doesn't apply to reference (pointer to object) types, including pointers to Cocoa objects. So this stuff that you said, "not just the Foundation collections. There is no more need manually to manage copy versus mutableCopy (versus retain, whether ARC implied or explicit)." are wrong because it *doesn't* apply to Foundation collections, and the distinction between `copy` and `mutableCopy` *is* needed.

Comment: @newacct I think you're right and I was wrong so I've attempted a correction. As I believe the correction was sufficiently significant to render it no longer _my_ answer, I've tagged as community wiki. Hopefully what's there now is more accurate (discarding that e.g. some blocks live on the stack so technically the reference/value distinction was in Objective-C too, but in a very limited fashion (and, yes, I'm discounting tagged pointers for semantic reasons)).